# Is this light sensor circuit correct?

Tags: capacitor, photodiode

I want to be able to accurately measure the light which hits a photodiode, during a specific exposure time.

The exposure is switched via MOSFET via input A.  The idea is that you drive A high for a specific period of time, which charges C1, then measure the voltage at output point B.

I am not sure about these things:

- R1 - This is so you can measure the voltage at B even after the MOSFET is switched off. Is it necessary?
- R2 - This is to slowly reset the capacitor to 0.  Maybe it would be better to just have a way to zero the capacitor via another MOSFET?
- R3 - Do we need this at all?

Any critiques welcome.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fujW7h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are you illuminating this with? And what is the device that is reading this? What is the exposure time and what is the frequency it is being measured with?

Comment: Where did your *light sensor circuit* come from?

Comment: Capacitor value for C1 of 1uF will take a very long time to charge. I'm using 47pf, and a RED LED for the photodiode. Capacitor voltage rises about 3V in 20ms, when illuminated indoors from daylight entering a window. A microcontroller is used to discharge the capacitor (which is connected from diode anode to GND. Was surprised to find microcontroller leakage currents were much less than 1nA.

Comment: I didn't work out any numbers, so I could change the capacitor values if needed.

Comment: @Captain You will need to discuss what you mean by "measure the light." First question: *Is this an irradiation measurement or an illumination measurement?* When you write something like "The exposure is switched..." I start thinking about still photos and movies for some reason. And that almost always isn't irradiation but instead illumination.

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you are trying to build a sample-and-hold circuit along with an averaging of the light over the sample time.

Rs is not required and should be set to0.

The main issue:

The photo-diode is a current source. When the FET is closed, the diode current is divided between the C and R2. When the FET is open the current split is different with most  in R2 and some through R1-C series combination.

So the configuration can do none of what is asked of it.

1. During averaging time, all of the diode current must pass through the capacitor.
2. During the sampling interval, none of the diode current can pass through the capacitor. But since the diode is a current source, the current must be diverted around the capacitor while maintaining the capacitor voltage. If the sampling interval is short enough, then diversion may not be necessary.
3. During the hold interval (or at least at the end of it), the capacitor is discharged.

Buffering a grounded capacitor with an op-amp is a good choice. Then an FET can be used to discharge the capacitor.

Clearly you put some thought into this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Actually I was hoping to operate it in a stateless, continuous, fashion.  That's why the cap drains itself continuously.  The MOSFET is actually there both as a shutter and both to block noise that I know the system will generate (e.g. from a flash).

Answer (score 1):

Have something similar built on a breadboard, using a PIC 12F1572 to do the capacitor discharge, and to measure charge time.
 A RED LED is used as a photodetector diode. It is also used as an indicator after a light-measuring period is finished.

- R2 limits current through the LED when RA4 is pulled HIGH, and RA5 is pulled LOW...the LED lights up.
- When RA5 is pulled HIGH and RA4 is switched to become a GPIO input pin, capacitor C2 slowly charges with photocurrent from the LED.
- When RA4 is driven LOW, the capacitor discharges to zero volts. LED photocurrents are shunted to Vss as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQs5Hi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 In this application, no analog-to-digital converter is used (there is a 10-bit ADC inside that might be used to measure charge time). Instead, a counter is started after C2 has been discharged to zero, and RA4 is switched from **logic 0 output** - to **high-impedance GPIO input**. RA4 is polled until it charges up to a **logic HIGH** by D1's photocurrent, then the counter is stopped and count value saved.
Charge time is inversely proportional to photocurrent, and hence the counter value is also inversely-proportional to photocurrent. A 24-bit counter is used, which would overflow after four seconds. A four-second charge time would correspond to roughly 23 picoamps photocurrent...not counting internal leakage current.

 Leakage current of RA4, C2 affects linearity at the near-darkness end. In very bright light, count value is small...in this case, a larger-value capacitor could be substituted for C2.

It may be possible to allow C2 to charge for a fixed time, with RA4 set as analog input, so that an ADC measurement may be triggered after a time-out, as OP has suggested. In this case, internal ADC capacitance must be charged as well (in parallel with C2, about 10pf). This has not been tried. ADC resolution of 10 bits is inferior to a 24-bit count.

Comment: The logic input threshold is not very accurate, and will probably change over time and temperature. And unless you use a Schmitt trigger input, it will enter a linear region that will draw excess current. Why not use a built-in comparator?

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, that PIC1272 does have a comparator that would be useful. Seems to have similar input characteristics as the ADC. I'd suggest that internal voltage reference (FVR) be set for +2.048V for the comparator.  Leakage currents for GPIO are spec'd at +/- 5nA over temperature range...at room temp, leakage seems much lower.  Not spec'd is bias current & offset current, but I'd suggest it might be included in leakage. Comparator offset voltage error seems inferior to ADC offset...but it may be OK at fixed temperature (temp dependency not spec'd).

Comment: If you charge the cap directly from the diode, it will end up at whatever max voltage the diode provides, for me it's something like 0.3v -- what if that never triggers the input pin?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Perhaps you're thinking of the photodiode running in solar-cell mode? In the circuit described, it runs reverse-biased (in a different quadrant than solar-cell mode) while collecting light. While reverse-biased, it remains a high-impedance current source for any voltage between GND and Vdd. One does need to observe its reverse-biased breakdown voltage, but that's usually greater than the microcontroller's Vdd of +5V.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  For the charging, does it not work better without your R2 resistor?  (Imagine you use a different diode for output).  Everybody told me my R3 resistor is pointless, I'm trying to understand why you have one.  Also, when you zero the cap, doesn't that cause a surge through the microprocessor and possibly cause damage?  Same with the current from the photodiode, doesn't it push the voltage a bit higher?

Comment: R2 is required for LED photo-detector **only if you drive the LED to emit light**...not required if you use a PIN-type photo diode. A photodiode could connect cathode directly to Vdd rather than RA5. Yes, cap discharge causes a momentary current surge when RA4 pulls it to GND: a small-value cap is easily discharged. Photodiode currents are tiny for small diodes. C2 should be significantly larger than photodiode zero-bias capacitance, but not so large that charge-time is painfully slow at low light levels. Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

Your circuit doesn't make sense. Did you study existing circuits first? or did you cook this up completely on your own? Photodiodes are normally used with transimpedance amplifiers otherwise they will have a very low, very slow, nonlinear output in most applications.

Forget the shutter part for now. All I will say about that is that the photodiode is likely too weak to drive the sampling circuit and the sampling circuit too much load to operate with any speed.

Let's just pay attention to the part that produces an output from the photodiode.Specifically the R3, D1, and V1.

1. Your circuit produces an output voltage that exceeds the 5V rail. Is this actually okay for you?
2. You reverse bias the photodiode which implies you want speed, but using a series resistor implies you don't need speed. What is the maximum reverse voltage tolerable by your photodiode?
3. R3 looks like it's intended as a current limiting resistor which doesn't make any sense. A series resistor is normally used as a load resistor to produce a usable signal level for photodiodes for very intensely illuminated photodiodes that need no amplification but signal levels come at the cost of speed. But the R3 is none of these.

Comment: So we can remove the R3, thanks.  What about the rest, will it work?  By exceeding the 5v you mean the tiny bit of voltage that the photodiode adds?

Comment: The rest: Start from scratch. Look up existing photodiodes circuits and then design your own based on those. It seems like you designed this circuit based on how you think photodiodes work without really looking anything up.

Comment: OK but what specifically is wrong here?  If I remove R3, does the capacitor not charge?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Just everything is wrong which is why I didn't bother to elaborate further and said to start from scratch after looking at existing circuits. It's not even about whether the cap will charge up or not. It's that even if it does it won't be reflective of the illumination level since the nonlinearities in the way you are using the photodiode are playing off the way the meaning of the reading changes with shutter timing. You also still did not answer my initial questions about the circuit's operating conditions. These matter.

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about the shutter until you have a proper way to actually produce an output from the photodiode. A photodiode is linear when operated as a current source but that means you actually need to operate it as a current source. It's not a current source automatically. The way you describe your sampling circuit makes it sound like you want to use your photodiode as a current source but you aren't actually doing that.

Comment: However, once your produce a circuit that actually operates your photodiode as a current source then you can produce a current or voltage output however you want since operating the photodiode as a current source doesn't mean that the output must be a current output since transimpedance amplifiers exist that convert the current reading to an voltage reading which tends to be more convenient. Then you can read the current or voltage directly or integrate them. It's arbitrary after that point.

Comment: How does the circuit produce a voltage higher than the 5V rail? Does the LED act as a photocell and generate current?

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes. A solar cell/panel is just a kind of special purpose photodiode after all.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I am trying to make a basic TOF distance sensor.  The idea is that I output a square wave from an IR LED and measure the phase shift of the reflected light by switching the "collection" to two capacitors in sync with the output signal, and comparing the charge collected.  I was trying to avoid having separate collection and measuring phases by allowing the system to run continuously, by slowly draining the caps via resistor, and thus being able to measure the difference in voltage across two points at any given time.  Perhaps that gives context to the circuit.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman You can't use LEDs for phase shift applications since the light is incoherent. You need lasers and methods to overlap the outgoing beam on top of the inncoming beam and feed both to a photodetector.

Comment: The phase shift is in the square wave, not the light waves. It seems like it's possible to use LEDs, see https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/Infrared-Illumination-for-Time-of-Flight-Applications.pdf

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Hmmm. Interesting, but that is a high speed application. You definitely needs a transimpedance amp circuit for that, and likely a fancy one with extras for speed. Your circuit is too slow and your photodiode is being operated in a slow manner. This is a basic: TIA https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu535/tidu535.pdf?ts=1676261180501. A fancy one starts to look like his: https://electrooptical.net/static/oldsite/www/frontends/frontends.pdf You can add your integration stuff on top of that.